# R.java: Syntax error on tokens

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android development (have some Obj-C experience with Cocoa Touch though). I was testing my first Android app as I encountered these syntax errors:

> Syntax error on token "100000", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
>
> Syntax error on token "11", delete this token
>
> Syntax error on token "2", delete this token
>
> Syntax error on token "5000", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
>
> Syntax error on token "61", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
>
> Syntax error on token "69", invalid VariableDeclaratorId

When I double clicked them, they appeared to be in the file `R.java` and I have no idea how they are caused.

```
   public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 100000=0x7f020000;
        public static final int 11ba=0x7f020001;
        public static final int 2values=0x7f020002;
        public static final int 5000=0x7f020003;
        public static final int 61=0x7f020004;
        public static final int 69=0x7f020005;
   .....
```

It would be great if someone can tell how this is caused.

[updates]

[MarsAtomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305826/marsatomic) suggested that it is caused by not following the naming conventions for Android resources and perhaps having rawables named "5000", "69", which is, as a matter of fact, true in this case.

After changing the names, these exceptions didn't occur anymore.

But I would still like to know why having images in numeral names would trigger this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment has disappeared somehow, but... every language has naming conventions.  Conventions are often just based on some semi-arbitrary heuristic because you have to have rules (e.g. it's slightly more clear that 'a1' denotes a variable name, whereas a variable named '1' could be confused for a value).

You can accept this answer as the canonical answer or not -- personally, I'm not bothered who gets what credit.

Answer (score 3):

> After changing the names, this exceptions didn't occur anymore.
>
> But I would still like to know why this is happening.

Because the names of those resources are used as field names in an auto-generated Java source file (`R.java`), and they aren't valid Java field names. Java field names must start with a letter. Details on the characters allowed in field names [here in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

(Really, [MarsAtomic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2305826/marsatomic) should be getting the credit for this, but doesn't seem to have seen the reposted question.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare variable names starting with numbers.

Comment: It's quite clear that the OP *didn't* write the code quoted. It's being auto-generated from something *else* the OP created, and he/she doesn't know what that other thing is. (Neither do I, not having done Android development.)

Answer (score 0):

R.class is auto-generated, if you change something in it,it won't work correctly.

Thy to Clean and Build your Project.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error in

```
public static final class drawable {
```

the most common mistake is a named `.png` file in your res folder starting with a number.

For example `1_pic.png`, `2015_22_22pic.png` and so on.

Right way: `pic_1.png`

Answer (score 0):

Among all folders located inside \ res \ and look for a file with the name different from the others, as 00000002. If you find, just delete it. Then click the name of your project in eclipse and then press the F5 key to refresh it. Thus the error will disappear and your R file will be updated.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the RES directories. You might have a file with the numerical sequence mentioned above, eg 00000002. To solve the problem, simply remove it from the folder.